# TableLayoutPanels inside Panel AutoScroll issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I currently have a `GroupBox`, which holds a `Panel`, which holds multiple `TableLayoutPanel` controls. The reason i want to do this is so that i can place headers, buttons and options between the table layout panels, but have everything in the `GroupBox` seem to be "scrollable" even though the `Panel` is the one handling the scrolling.

A perfect example of this is the "Advanced Settings" for an Application Pool in IIS7... sorry i can't really put this visual into text more than that.

The problem I am having is that the `Panel` simply does not want to "enable" its AutoScroll even when there are `TableLayoutPanel` s that very obviously go beyond the bottom of the `Panel` itself. However, if i place a `Label` there instead, it works.

Is there a reason why this is happening? Should there be some setting set for the `TableLayoutPanel` in order to have it register in the `Panel` control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that by having the TableLayoutPanels anchors set to None, the scrolling didn`t work. As soon as i set them to Top, Left, the scrolling enabled.